# Where is the object, when I assign a new object to a existing php obj?

Tags: php, oop, memory-management

For example:

```
1 $abc = new MyObj();
2 $abc = new MyAnotherObj();
```

I assign `MyObj` in the first line, and the second line will assign another object. Where does the object assigned in first line go? Is it still in memory, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the second line executes, the first object will have its destructor called and will be deallocated.  PHP's GC does reference counting; when you overwrite the only reference to the `MyObj` instance, the number of references drops to zero and the GC destroys the object.

Note that this would happen no matter what you assigned to `$abc` -- you could have assigned `"foobar"` or `42` or `null` or even `new MyObj()` (a *new* instance of `MyObj`) and the old object will be destroyed.

See [this example on ideone](https://ideone.com/STdv9).

Comment: When number of references went to 0 - GC **marks** object as ready-to-collect and doesn't collect it right now, or even ever.

Comment: Yes, it does.  At least the official PHP implementation does.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php --- documentation says other (look at the graph)

Comment: I did not say that the memory is immediately *freed*, only that the object is immediately *destroyed*.  I recognize that the term "deallocated" might be a bit ambiguous in this context; I did not mean to imply that the memory is returned to the underlying OS.  This graph is also specific to *self-referential objects*.  Those objects won't be collected without an object graph scan anyway, since *their reference count will never be zero*.

Answer (score 1):

It would be garbage collected in any other language, as there is no longer any reference to it (and you would be unable to reference it further at this point).  It's one of those things I just wouldn't do in PHP (or, really, any other language)... if you need a reference to that first object, save it first, or don't use the same variable name.

Comment: What's wrong with php? And with any other language? Any GC that can count references to object is good enough to collect such objects.

Comment: PHP didn't have a full garbage collector before version 5.3.

Comment: I didn't suggest that anything is wrong with PHP.  I just don't know how PHP handles that.  Please be more careful with your assumptions.  Edit: Further, I wouldn't do that in any language because expecting the original object to exist without a reference and then somehow expecting to find it again is not any breed of sane.

Comment: as I know, the objective c will still remain the source code in memory at some where. Then, memory leak.

Comment: @kungphu: what assumptions I should be care of do you mean?

Comment: Your comment assumed I suggested something was wrong with PHP.  I simply stated that I would not do this, particularly in a language the GC of which I wasn't sure of; the code in the question just isn't something I would consciously do, ever, but it's worse when you don't know how the GC works.  Anyway, it's irrelevant to the poster's question. :)